# Formatting floats in dataframes when using to_dict

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe imported from a CSV with integer columns that have some missing values. Since these get converted to floats on import, how can I format the floats back to integer representations when export to a dictionary using `to_dict`?

I have tried setting the default display format for dataframe floats using the `pd.set_option` function and I have tried using `float_format` with `to_dict`, but the latter raises an exception because that is not a valid option.

Comment: What do you mean 'these get converted to floats on import'? Do you import the data from a CSV file?

Comment: please provide some sample data of your input and desired output